# Pytorch Model causing 500 server error in Django App

Tags: django, pytorch, torch, yolo, yolov5

This is My Django project [Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Grw.png), and in the "bills" app, I am trying to import my YOLOV5 pre-trained custom model (which works fine on its own).
So Views.py :

```
def crop(request):
model = torch.hub.load('../yolov5-master', 'custom', path='../best.pt', force_reload=True)
return render(request, '../templates/results.html')
```

This is causing my app to return a 500 server error when hitting that URL; I know the model is causing it because if I comment out that first line

```
#model = torch.hub.load('../yolov5-master', 'custom', path='../best.pt', force_reload=True)
```

Then the page shows fine.
I looked up many articles on how to load a Pytorch model into Django and it seems I am doing it right, can you please help me figure out what's the problem ?

Comment: Please share with us the full traceback error

Comment: @NKSM I am not sure how to do that, I actually would appreciate it if someone can tell me how to trace the error, all am getting is : 
"GET /bills/crop HTTP/1.1" 500 145
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to path. You can try this in `views.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourappname.settings")
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings

model = torch.hub.load('../yolov5-master', 'custom', path=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'best.pt'), force_reload=True)
```

In your `settings.py`, you will first need to configure your `MEDIA_ROOT` path like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploaded_media')
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still getting the same server error (500)

Comment: Can you plz check which line is causing error.

Comment: print this in your views: `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'best.pt'` and check if the model is placed in the correct location

Comment: This line is causing the error : 
model = torch.hub.load('../yolov5-master', 'custom', path=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'best.pt'), force_reload=True)
And When printing the os.path.join you asked me to I get : 
C:\Bill_OCR_DEV\uploaded_media\best.pt
So the model weights are placed in the correct location